# How to integrate one website into another while sharing authentification?

Tags: php, symfony, iframe, curl

I manage a website. Let's name it Website A. Website A is written in PHP, procedural-style, with a few different and out-dated frameworks in it. No surprise, it is a mess to maintain and to upgrade. I want to create Website B with a clean framework (Symfony2) and using OOP. Slowly I will refactor Website A into Website B.  Any new features will also be done in Website B.

The catch? I want content from Website A to appear in the layout of Website B. I can't simply include the files of Website A in Website B as the configuration of it messes with the framework of Website B. What's the best way to achieve it? Using an iframe? Using Curl? Or using another method?

When I tried using AJAX, the integration went smoothly. Since they're on the same domain the cookies are shared, so even if the user logs in on Website B, Website A is aware of it. It was, however, slow to output and I had problems with the responsive design (even though I know responsive iframe can be done).

When using Curl, it was much faster to output and no responsive problems. However, since it's PHP that connects to Website A, I need to find a way to pass the authentication from one Website to another.

Both methods need some work in order to function properly. I lean toward the curl method, but is there a "best practice" in my case?

Both websites has personalized content, it's not simply a firewall-type authentification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you're authentication involves personalised content, which would be harder, or just firewalled content. This would make a difference. The best approach I've seen to this problem was to use nginx as a reverse proxy.

Comment: There's personalized content involved. Do you have an example on how nginx was used?

Comment: It was at this presentation in Symfony Live London 2013 - http://phpvideo.org/video/symfonylive-london-2013-craig-marvelley-transforming-a-legacy-php-app-using-symfony2-varnish.

Comment: Thanks for the video. I didn't know about varnish.